# Azure Schema registry + Spark Structured Streaming + Kafka/EventHub compatibility

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub, confluent-schema-registry

Is there a way to use AZURE Schema Registry with Spark Structured Streaming? (not the opensource schema registry).

Ideally I would use some high level library like Abris (https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS), to read and write avro from/to Kafka with automatically registering/ reading the df schema in the schema registry. However, I have not managed to find anything at all that could enable spark to do to_avro or from_avro against an Azure Schema Registry.

There is an open PR that could add the functionality for some column types https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/pull/615

There seems to be an unmainained repo that at least tried to do the from_avro part (https://github.com/arerlend/azure-schemaregistry-spark)

Anybody knows about a good way how to interact with Azure Schema Registry with Spark Structured Streaming?

Comment: The only real way would be to use a UDF, which is all from/to_avro functions are. You'd just have to edit some code to swap out the Confluent dependencies with Azure ones, or implement the basic HTTP(?) calls on your own

Answer (score 0):

You can read the schema definitions just as easily with Schema Registry and Databricks as you can with Open-Source. Simply pass the Schema Registry address as an input to to avro/from avro. Here's an example from the Databricks documentation, which is linked in the further reading section:

```
val schemaRegistryAddr = "https://myhost:8081"
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", servers)
  .option("subscribe", "t")
  .load()
  .select(
    from_avro($"key", "t-key", schemaRegistryAddr).as("key"),
    from_avro($"value", "t-value", schemaRegistryAddr).as("value"))
```

If you're using Databricks to execute your tasks, you may use the native from avro/to avro methods. If not, you can utilize one of the many Open-Source options available.

**Reference:**
[Structured Streaming and Apache Kafka Schema Registry](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/structured-streaming-apache-kafka-schema-registry/read)

[Schema Registry integration in Spark Structured Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/schema-registry-integration/avro-data-and-schema-registry.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the example you provided seems to be using Confluent Schema registry as well:
schemaRegistryClient: org.spark_project.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient = org.spark_project.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient@6c449640

I am familiar working with confluent schema registry, but not the Azure one (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/schema-registry-overview)

Comment: This library is able to create the client for Azure scheme registry - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/schemaregistry/azure-data-schemaregistry-apacheavro/README.md#getting-started

But where would we get the schema registry address:port e.g. for     from_avro($"key", "t-key", schemaRegistryAddr).as("key") 
I am unable to find this anywhere in the Azure docs/portal. 
Thanks again for any help.